# Javascript: Create loop to concatinate results from checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I have tried all day to do this - and searched too.

I have checkboxes in an html form. If they are checked I need to immediate concat and display the values into a seperate text area. My function currenty works but I need to create a loop becuase I cant be certain of the number of check boxes as they are dynamic.

My function is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

            function combGenderSeekingGender() {
                if (document.jomsForm.jsgenderseekinggender1.checked){
                    alert("input1 is checked");
                    var input1 = document.jomsForm.jsgenderseekinggender1.value;
                }else{
                    alert("input1 is NOT checked");
                    var input1 = "";
                }


                if (document.jomsForm.jsgenderseekinggender2.checked){
                    alert("input2 is checked");
                    var input2 = document.jomsForm.jsgenderseekinggender2.value;
                }else{
                    alert("input2 is NOT checked");
                    var input2 = "";
                }

                if (document.jomsForm.jsgenderseekinggender3.checked){
                    alert("input3 is checked");
                    var input3 = document.jomsForm.jsgenderseekinggender3.value;
                }else{
                    alert("input3 is NOT checked");
                    var input3 = "";
                }

                if (document.jomsForm.jsgenderseekinggender4.checked){
                    alert("input4 is checked");
                    var input4 = document.jomsForm.jsgenderseekinggender4.value;
                }else{
                    alert("input4 is NOT checked");
                    var input4 = "";
                }

                var tmpInput =input1 + "-" + input2 + "-" + input3 + "-" + input4;  
                document.jomsForm.jsgenderseekinggender.value = tmpInput.replace(/^[\s-]+|[\s-]+$/g,"");                    
            }

        </script>
```

This function is called in a loop that dynamically creates my checkbox as such:

```
  $html .= '<input type="checkbox" onClick="combGenderSeekingGender()" id="jsgenderseekinggender'.$elementCnt.'" name="jsgenderseekinggender'.$elementCnt.'" value="'.$genderseekinggenderItem.'"/>';
```

Everything works fine but I need to remove the hardcoded js functionality and create a pure loop. I am able to pass the elementCount to the function which will help set the limit but I cant seem to get the rest of the loop to work out becuase I can seem to define dynamic variable names.

I basically Ive been trying variations of this:

```
function combGenderSeekingGender(numResults) {
                    var input=[];
                    for (ii=1;ii<=numResults;ii++){
                        if (document.jomsForm.jsgenderseekinggender[ii].checked){
                            alert("input"+ii+" is checked");
                            var input[ii] = document.jomsForm.jsgenderseekinggender[ii].value;
                        }else{
                            alert("input"+ii+" is NOT checked");
                            var input[ii] = "";
                        }

                    }


                    var tmpInput =input1 + "-" + input2 + "-" + input3 + "-" + input4;  
                    document.jomsForm.jsgenderseekinggender.value = tmpInput.replace(/^[\s-]+|[\s-]+$/g,"");                    
                }
```

Of course this is more psuedo code than anything else because I know its not the correct way t code it.  Any advice to get the correct syntax would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: where is the value of checkbox declared?

Comment: The value is declared in a variable $genderseekinggenderItem which is populated by a loop:  foreach ($result as $genderseekinggenderItem) . You can see it in the input tag

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery:

```
var result = "";
$("input:checked" ).each(function(){
    result = result + "-" + $(this).val();
});
```

This will loop thru all the selected checkboxes and concatenate their values to result.

Comment: Ok Ill do some research on jqery. Thanks for the hint.